# Inserting objects into database from Flex app not working

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flash-builder4.5

I am trying to make a mobile app that inserts information into a database and while I have it pulling information and I have created my services, when I use the standard create service that Flash Builder 4.6 automatically makes, it just does not insert anything at all into the database.

I have tried everything and I am now with the following code:

I first create a variable array with the values of the service call

```
....
 protected var Coordinatelist2:Coordinatelist = new Coordinatelist();
```

I then created a function to fill in the information. The variables SesID, Lat and Long are declared when my button is pressed.

```
....
  protected function createCoordinatelist(item:Coordinatelist):void
            {
                Coordinatelist2.SessionID = SesID;
                Coordinatelist2.Latitude = Lat;
                Coordinatelist2.Longitude = Long;
                createCoordinatelistResult.token = coordinatelistService.createCoordinatelist(Coordinatelist2);
            }
```

After this, I then go and add the following line of code to the end of my button function.

```
 .....
 createCoordinatelist(Coordinatelist2);
```

Now, as far as I am concerned, this should then be writing to the database the items of SesID, Lat and Long using the created service token, but when I do this, nothing has entered into the database at all.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Seems like more code is required can you send your entire code and the place where you inserting the data to the data base thanks

Comment: Agreed with commentor above at least include details regarding what server environment you're using, you are probably going to need to debug this "server side" by using the logs to monitor what's going on you can use a proxy program like charles or wireshark to monitor the requests from the client and see responses from the server, this will allow you to confirm that everything is making it's way out of the client code okay and see if any error response is returned from the server side.

Comment: Did you mean item.SessionId = SesID? When calling  createCoordinatelist(Coordinatelist2), Coordinatelist2 becomes item.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but I came right. I needed to commit the token after creating it using createCoordinatelistResult.token = coordinatelistService.commit()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion but I came right.

What I found I had not done was commit my token once I created it. I simply used `createCoordinatelistResult.token = coordinatelistService.commit();` and it worked perfectly.

Thanks for the feedback